# Fortran issue: Argument of "xx" is one type at (2) but is some other type at (1)

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, fortran77, g77

I have a few "Argument is one type at (1) but is some other type at (2) errors coming up in my program, but I'm not sure how to modify it.
Is there some other way of writing the arguments than what I've done?

Ps. I compile in g77. But I also tried in gfortran, where the error that comes up is of the kind "Rank mismatch in argument 'z' at (1) (scalar and rank-1)".

Here are the errors coming up:

```
geomalb.f: In subroutine `atmsetup':
geomalb.f:1083: 
         SUBROUTINE ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
                                    1
geomalb.f:1122: (continued):
         SUMT=SUMT+(EFFG(Z(J))*ADEN)*( Z(J-1)-Z(J))*XMU(J)
                     2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `z' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
geomalb.f:80: warning:
         COLDEN(J)=RHOP*(PRESS(J+1)-PRESS(J))/EFFG(Z(J))
                                              1
geomalb.f:1122: (continued):
         SUMT=SUMT+(EFFG(Z(J))*ADEN)*( Z(J-1)-Z(J))*XMU(J)
                    2
Argument #1 of `effg' is one type at (2) but is some other type at (1) [info -f g77 M GLOBALS]
geomalb.f:80: warning:
         COLDEN(J)=RHOP*(PRESS(J+1)-PRESS(J))/EFFG(Z(J))
                                              1
geomalb.f:1124: (continued):
         SUMB=SUMB+(EFFG(Z(J))*ADEN)*( Z(J-1)-Z(J))*28.01340
                    2
Argument #1 of `effg' is one type at (2) but is some other type at (1) [info -f g77 M GLOBALS]
geomalb.f:72: warning:
         CALL ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
              1
geomalb.f:1083: (continued):
         SUBROUTINE ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
                    2
Argument #2 (named `z') of `atmsetup' is one type at (2) but is some other type at (1) [info -f g77 M GLOBALS]
```

Part of the program:

```
      SUBROUTINE ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
     & CH4,H2,XN2,AR,IPRINT)
      PARAMETER (NMAX=201)
      DIMENSION CH4(1),H2(1),XN2(1),AR(1)
      DIMENSION TLINAL(NMAX),DLINAL(NMAX),PLINAL(NMAX)
      DIMENSION DEN(1), PRESS(1), TEMP(1), XMU(1)
      CALL LINDAL(NLEVEL,Z,TLINAL,DLINAL,PLINAL)
      DO J=1,NLEVEL
      TEMP(J)= TLINAL(J)
      DEN(J)= DLINAL(J)
      PRESS(J)=PLINAL(J)
      ENDDO
      DO 1000 ITS =1,20
      CH4(NLEVEL)=PCH4(TEMP(NLEVEL))*RHCH4/PRESS(NLEVEL)
      DO 134 J=NLEVEL-1,1,-1
      CH4SAT=PCH4(TEMP(J))/PRESS(J)
      CH4(J)=AMIN1(CH4SAT,CH4(NLEVEL),CH4(J+1))
  134  CONTINUE
      DO 20 J=1,NLEVEL
      H2(J)=FH2
      IF (FARGON .LT. 0.) THEN
      AR(J)=(-FARGON-28.0134+25.8554*H2(J)+11.9708*CH4(J))/11.9346
      ELSE
      IF (FARGON .EQ. 0.) THEN
      AR(J)=0.0
      ELSE
      AR(J)=FARGON
      ENDIF
      ENDIF
      XN2(J)=1.0 - H2(J) - CH4(J) -AR(J)
      XMU(J)=28.0134*XN2(J)+2.158*H2(J)+16.0426*CH4(J)+39.948*AR(J)
  20   CONTINUE
      SUMT=PLINAL(1)*6.02E23/10.
      SUMB=SUMT
      TLAST=TEMP(NLEVEL)
      DO J=2,NLEVEL
      DENF=294.1/(XN2(J)*294.1 + CH4(J)*410. + H2(J)*136. + AR(J)*277.8)
      DEN(J) = DLINAL(J)*DENF
      ADEN=(DEN(J)-DEN(J-1))/ALOG(DEN(J)/DEN(J-1))
      SUMT=SUMT+(EFFG(Z(J))*ADEN)*( Z(J-1)-Z(J))*XMU(J)
      ADEN=(DLINAL(J)-DLINAL(J-1))/ALOG(DLINAL(J)/DLINAL(J-1))
      SUMB=SUMB+(EFFG(Z(J))*ADEN)*( Z(J-1)-Z(J))*28.01340
      PRESS(J)=PLINAL(J)*SUMT/SUMB
      TEMP(J) =TLINAL(J)*(SUMT/SUMB)*(1./DENF)
      ENDDO
  30  CONTINUE
      DT= ABS(TEMP(NLEVEL)-TLAST)
      IF (DT .LT. 0.001) GO TO 1001
1000  CONTINUE
1001  IF (IPRINT .LT. 0) RETURN
      WRITE (6,139)RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,DT
      DO 135 J=1,NLEVEL-1
      WRITE(6,140)J,Z(J),PRESS(J),DEN(J),TEMP(J),
     &          CH4(J)*PRESS(J)/PCH4(TEMP(J))
     &         ,CH4(J)*100.,XN2(J)*100.,H2(J)*100.,AR(J)*100.,XMU(J)
     &         ,(TEMP(J+1)-TEMP(J))/(Z(J+1)-Z(J))
  135    CONTINUE
      J=NLEVEL
      WRITE(6,140)J,Z(J),PRESS(J),DEN(J),TEMP(J),
     &    CH4(J)*PRESS(J)/PCH4(TEMP(J))
     &    ,CH4(J)*100.,XN2(J)*100.,H2(J)*100.,AR(J)*100.,XMU(J)
  139 FORMAT(///'   BACKGROUNG ATMOSPHERE AT LEVELS'/
     & ' SURFACE HUMIDITY OF CH4:',F5.3,'  H2 MIXING RATIO:',F6.4,
     & ' ARGON SETTING:',F8.4/'  FINAL CONVERGENCE ON TEMP:',F10.5
     & , '   LINDAL ET AL SCALING'/
     &' LVL ALTITUDE  P(BARS)  DEN(CM-3) TEMP RH-CH4'
     & , ' %CH4  %N2   %H2  %AR   MU   DT/DZ'  )
  140 FORMAT(1X,I3,F8.3,1P2E10.3,0PF7.2,F5.2,2F6.2,2F5.2,4F6.2)
      RETURN
      END SUBROUTINE
      END
```

And earlier in the program this is how I call the subroutine:

```
      CALL ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
     & CH4,H2,XN2,AR,IPRINT)
```

Comment: *I compile in g77*  Well stop, start using gfortran as your principal compiler, or Intel Fortran or Cray's compiler or IBM's or Absoft or PGI.  And start using `implicit none` in every scope in your program.  You're becoming a regular here, which is nice for us, but help us to help you and start adopting modern Fortran programming practices. You don't have to make a huge effort to modernise all your code at once, you can introduce new ones piece by piece.  A good start would be to write declarations of all the dummy arguments for the subroutine that you are currently having trouble with.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks for the reply. The reason I use g77 is because this is a program written in 1987 from which I just want to obtain a text file with values that I can use in my python code. I never actually learned fortran which is why I'm having a lot of trouble with it now. 
I could change the whole program, although it is about 5000 lines.. For the sake of my purpose, I think it's easier to try and compile it as it is. I did compile in gfortran too though and the "rank mismatch" error comes up which seems related to the g77 error.

Comment: That's right, the gfortran message is a more explicit report of the same error that g77 reports.  And your strategy of not learning Fortran but relying on strangers on SO to sort out your problems for you seems to be working well :-)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark So what you're saying is that I should write declarations of all the arguments that right now are causing trouble, and then compile in gofortran? I can definitely use gfortran, although I thought that I was already defining my arguments here in the program?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I wish I could learn Fortran and I definitely will eventually, but I'm on a tight deadline and right now the only reason I would need fortran is for this one program. So unfortunately, I have to rely on strangers from SO for this :(

Comment: Really all I am saying is this: modern Fortran, available with gfortran (and many other compilers but not, if memory serves, g77) implements many features to support safe programming, features not available before the 1990 standard was published, and implemented.  These features include requiring explicit declarations (ie using `implicit none`), procedure interface checking (a compiler option), and lots more.

Comment: I agree with Mark completely. And gfortran is much better compiler than g77 even for old codes you do not change at all. The error checking and debugging features are much more advanced. We can't solve for you very single error, but those you have there seem to be indeed connected with the declarations of the variables. Use `implicit none` to get much better and more explicit hints from the compiler. BTW, as I said in your earlier question. `REAL DEN(*)` is much better then `DIMENSION DEN(1)` for many reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not provide any type information for your variables and instead rely on implicit typing.  Under default implicit typing rules, your variables `Z` and `EFFG` are declared as:

```
real :: Z
real :: EFFG
```

Both `Z` and `EFFG` are real variables of rank 0 (scalar).  You reference these variables in the following way

```
EFFG(Z(J))
```

This is a rank mismatch.  You access `Z` as a rank 1 variable and `EFFG` as a rank 1 variable, but they were implicitly defined as rank 0 variables.

The fix is to properly declare the variables as rank 1 arrays.  In the comments you note that switching to gfortran changed the error from a generic "types are different" error into a specific "rank mismatch".  This is a much more helpful error message, and others have noted you should be able (once your issues are all fixed) to compile your code with gfortran with no (or only minor) changes over what g77 compiles.  It is worthwhile to adopt modern practices and a simple start would be to change

```
       SUBROUTINE ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
      & CH4,H2,XN2,AR,IPRINT)
       PARAMETER (NMAX=201)
       DIMENSION CH4(1),H2(1),XN2(1),AR(1)
       DIMENSION TLINAL(NMAX),DLINAL(NMAX),PLINAL(NMAX)
       DIMENSION DEN(1), PRESS(1), TEMP(1), XMU(1)
```

into

```
       SUBROUTINE ATMSETUP(NLEVEL,Z,RHCH4,FH2,FARGON,TEMP,PRESS,DEN,XMU,
      & CH4,H2,XN2,AR,IPRINT)
       implicit none
       integer NMAX
       real CH4, H2, XN2, AR, TLINAL, DLINAL, PLINAL, DEN, PRESS, TEMP
       real xmu, Z, EFFG, RHCH4, FH2, FARGON, ADEN, CH4SAT, DENF, DT
       real SUMB, SUMT, TLAST, PCH4
       integer NLEVEL, IPRINT, ITS, J

       PARAMETER (NMAX=201)
       DIMENSION CH4(1),H2(1),XN2(1),AR(1)
       DIMENSION TLINAL(NMAX),DLINAL(NMAX),PLINAL(NMAX)
       DIMENSION DEN(1), PRESS(1), TEMP(1), XMU(1)
```

Note that this change will not fix your error, as I have not consulted my crystal ball to determine the dimensions of `Z` and `EFFG`.  All I have done is add explicit types, which should be understood by the ancient g77 compiler (and gfortran in fixed-form).  Also note I've assumed default implicit types in determining the explicit types used above, and if they are not what you expected them to be then that is an even better reason to adopt explicit typing.